# "Argument 'DateValue' cannot be converted to type 'Date'"

Tags: vb.net, date

All

I'm a beginner working in VB 2010. I'm working on a reminder tied into Task Scheduler until I get to working with "open at a this time" kind of thing.  Anyway, I want it read dated lines from a text file until the date is more than 7 days from today.  It will auto read any non-dated line until it reaches + 7 days.  Also I would like it to work with any date format mdy, dmy or ymd.

If it makes a difference in Control Panel>Region my Home Country = United States and the Short Date = yyyy-MM-DD.

Using "Copy execption detail to the clipboard" I got the following:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
HResult=-2147467262 
Message=Argument 'DateValue' cannot be converted to type 'Date'. 
Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic
```

When I run:

```
        Dim regDate As Date = Date.Now()

        Dim Date1 As String = regDate.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy")
        Dim Date2 As String = regDate.ToString("MM-dd")
        Dim Date3 As String = regDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
        Dim Date4 As String = regDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")

        Dim D1_plus_7 As String = DateAdd("d", 7, Date1)
        Dim D2_plus_7 As String = DateAdd("d", 7, Date2)
        'Dim D3_plus_7 As String = DateAdd("d", 7, Date3) '< I get the err here
        Dim D4_plus_7 As String = DateAdd("d", 7, Date4)

        Console.WriteLine(D1_plus_7)
        Console.WriteLine(D2_plus_7)
        'Console.WriteLine(D3_plus_7)
        Console.WriteLine(D4_plus_7)
```

The commented lines were so I could make sure what would work after I got the error. Oh Date2 was just checking if it would work.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you
Bobbie

Comment: Probably the implicit conversion of the `string` fails. (It will use the overload of the function `DateAdd` with the `Object` parameter [MSDN url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcxe65wz.aspx).)

Comment: So basically you're saying though I can read the DMY date format I can't calculate new dates from it.

Comment: Or is it that I have to convert DMY dates to MDy or YMD to calculate with them?

Comment: Just provide the `DateTime` value and not a `string`. Besides, why not use the [`AddDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) method on the `DateTime` variable?

Comment: Because I haven"t played with it enough to know that I could.  I not afraid to play with things I just don't know things yet.

Comment: @ Styxxy Thank you now I understand how it works.  I learn funny.